# Store unwellformed XHTML in Basex DB

Tags: xquery, basex, xquery-3.0, xquery-3.1

I have to store XHTML which is not wellformed e.g.(<img href"tes.jpg">) so there is no closing element for element  or self close.

I am using the REST service to store data into database, below is the code:

```
 let $$DocPath:= 'D:\sample\'
 for $files in file:children($DocPath)
 let $filename := fn:tokenize($files,'\\')[fn:last()]
 return
  (
      db:replace('test',('\content\'||$filename),fn:doc($files),map{'skipcorrupt' : true()}),
      admin:write-log(fn:concat('Content ingested', ' ' , $filename))
  )
```

I have used option "skipcorrupt" but it didn't work and I am getting error while ingesting content:

(Line 369): The element type "img" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".]

Is there any option which I need to configure in the "web.xml" or ".basex" file, please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Replacing fn:doc with html:doc might do the job. Ensure that TagSoup is in the class path.

Comment: @ChristianGrün Thanks for the quick response, it worked Thanks lot.